# Catching every exception in Java EE web apps

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, exception

First, I am throwing run time exceptions for all unrecoverable exceptions, this causes these exceptions to travel up to the container, where I currently use an error page (defined in web.xml). In this error page is a scriptlet that invokes the logger.

The issue I am having with this is that the exception is no longer on the stack at this invocation. I have access to it from a request scope variable ("javax.servlet.error.message"). This string is the stack trace. I need this stack trace for logging purposes obviously, and on different app servers "javax.error_message" can be turned off for security reasons.......

So my question is, how can best log runtime exceptions from within Java EE apps without wrapping everything in this:

```
try {} catch (Exception e) {logger.log(...)}
```

?

I want some way to invoke the logger from the container maybe... right before the container catches the exception for example.

Comment: What framework are you using? Struts? Spring?

Comment: This will be framework indenpendent. We don't want it to tie to anything in particular (app server or framework). We are actually support 3 frameworks. These are plain j2ee/struts/JSF(in particular Oracle's adaption of JSF: ADF Faces). As for the back end, PL/SQL stored procedures or just SQL/jdbc... as for ADF Faces, it uses ADF Business components... which is similar to Toplink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. By adding a response filter and wrapping chain.doFilter(req, resp) like so:

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(req,resp);
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("", e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This works fine so far and isn't dependent on a particular framework or app server.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing I know of in Servlet API to accomplish this.

However, you can do this in Tomcat with an instance listener. You can install a listener in context.xml like this,

```
<InstanceListener>myapp.MyListener</InstanceListener>
```

Tomcat fires `InstanceEvent.AFTER_SERVICE_EVENT` event right after the container catches the exception and before it throws the exception again. You can invoke the logger right there.

Comment: Do you know if this can be done in Oracle Weblogic or Oracle Application Server?

Comment: No experience with other containers. It's very likely they all have something similar (probably undocumented) because the container needs the hook for its own lifecycle management.

Comment: It seems that Oracle does allow for this through JSF, which is where we will do this on our ADF Faces (a JSF implementation from Oracle): http://database.in2p3.fr/doc/oracle/Oracle_Application_Server_10_Release_3/web.1013/b28967/web_val008.htm

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the 'exception' object is present as a variable.. called 'exception' in your 'error' jsp. You could always use this object to log retrieve the exception information and log in in the error jsp itself.

Answer (score 0):

[AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) would be my first choice.

You define:

- join point (a runtime exception is thrown).
- advice (your code to log the exception).
- point cuts (which parts of your applications are "listening" this aspect).

Take a look at http://www.aspectj.org/